# Jquery Read Array of Select Dropdowns in Numbered Group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of select dropdowns as such:

```
<select name="item[1]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[2]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[3]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[4]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to parse through them using Jquery.  The number in the name is populated by the ID number of the item in my database.  I basically want to parse through each one, if it is a yes, then use the ID to get the price of the item from the database to calculate a total.  Is this even possible with Jquery?  I can do the rest of the code no problem, I just need help with parsing through all of the `item` and return the value and ID for each one.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: `$("select").each(function() { if (this.value == "Yes") //do stuff })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the jQuery [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and combine with [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the list of your selected items.

Here's a runnable snippet that returns an array of selected items after clicking the button. It's up to you to take the item ids and generate your price.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var ids = $('select[name^="item"]').map(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes")
      return this.name.replace(/\D/g,'');
    else 
      return null;
  }).toArray();
  
  alert(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="item[1]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[2]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[3]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[4]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<button>Get Price</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example (*the `getIds` method is the part you want*)

```js
function getIds(){
  var selected = $('select[name^="item["]').filter(function(){
    return this.value == 'Yes';
  }).map(function(){
    return this.name.match(/\d+/);
  });
  return selected.get();
}

// just for display purposes
// you should call the getIds() method when you need to..
$('select').change(function(){
  var ids = getIds();
  $('.results').text( ids );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="item[1]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[2]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[3]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<select name="item[4]">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<div class="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you could try something like this:

```
$("select[name^='item']").each(function(){
console.log($(this).attr("name") + ": " + $(this).find(":selected").attr("value"));
});
```

With a slight tweak, you could turn that into key value pairs, and then, if I understand the question correctly, potentially use `eval()` to get the desired value.